# Can our thesis supervisor forced us to publish the thesis paper?

Tags: thesis

I am an undergraduate student and I wrote my thesis in a group (5 members). It is a academic procedure that in the final year we have to perform thesis which have 3.00 credits and we have a supervisor for this.

we have completed our thesis paper and everything is OK according to our supervisor, we have completed every correction in our thesis report. After every correction is done the rule is that we have to submit our thesis report in a book format(black book). After that our external and supervisor gives us mark based on our performance as it is a academical course.But thing is that now he wants to publish our paper in a journal and conference, but we don't want to publish.

Since we disagreed, he don't want to publish our result and don't want to give us marks. Does he have the right to do so? Can he forced us to publish that paper with him? Now, he wants a bond sign in a application, in the application it is included that "We are bound to our supervisor that as long as our paper won't published in two journals and one conference we can't withdraw our academical certificate and mark sheet and we all have to bear all the cost in the procedure of publication and we are bound to meet with in any circumstances it doesn't matter we are in a job or anything and we can't deny to meet with him" the main thing is that from the beginning it was not included and we were not aware of this kind of issues. This agreement was not included at the beginning. What should we do?

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain *why* you don't want to publish?  Usually one really wants to publish one's work.

Comment: I don't understand what you "signed". Was this at the start of the work? What does it say?

Comment: "now he wanted a bond sign in a application that we can't withdraw our certificate and mark sheet as long as our thesis paper is not published." I'm sorry, but this makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah, I (still) have no idea what you're talking about. (1) Why don't you want to publish, (2) what does your professor want you to sign -- the last paragraph makes no sense, and (3) what happens if you don't sign?

Comment: @cag51 (1) we wanted to publish but he forced us to publish the paper. if he only wanted to publish then that would be okay but the thing is that he wanted our sign in a conditional and terms application that includes as i mentioned.  if we don't sign then he will block our academical progress as well as we can't get our certificate from the varsity.

Comment: RE your first sentence -- there is an impasse because he is forcing you to do what you already wanted to do? Sorry, this is getting more confusing...

Comment: See the Dean or Head or other advisors and **Don't sign anything** until this is sorted.

Comment: publication is not in that procedure. only procedure from the beginning is we have to complete our thesis work, defense our paper, make a complete report and then its done. we are good to go. but he is forcing us to publish that paper with him.@cag51

Comment: Thank you for your advice. we will definitely try.@SolarMike

Comment: @BobBrown i have edited my query please read again and help me out.

Comment: @AzorAhai i have edited my query please read again and help me out

Comment: @shuvo You added a lot of unnecessary details, but it's still unclear what "a bond sign in a application" is. If you are translating something, maybe you can give the original name so someone can help you out with the English? Also, you've quoted something, but that really doesn't sound like something someone would write in an official form. Is that an actual quote from this bond?

Comment: @shuvo  OK... the problem is you don't want to pay a fee to have your work published, right?

Comment: Your professor may be expected by the school and/or funding source to publish work done with students. They may not have required you to sign that at the start because they never expected anyone to not want to publish like this.

Comment: I could not understand what the contract is about. Please use punctuation.

Comment: I cannot really understand why publishing your thesis would be a bad thing. Most students would be happy if their thesis is published.

Answer (score 3):

General answer: you should talk with your undergraduate adviser. These are the people in the department of your university who specialize in resolving academic issues and conflicts, they will help you.

To me it seems that you have fulfilled the requirement (writing thesis) but now your supervisor is adding extra requirement of publishing. Maybe that was part of the deal from start, maybe it is something new. You should also mention that now the supervisor basically rescinded their approval of thesis and block your academic progress.

Comment: no that was not part of the deal from the start.